# Modify Canvas SVG Image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I have a svg image that I can use to draw to canvas:

```
    image = new Image()
    image.src = "image.svg"
```

Is it possible to modify `image` to, for example, change the colour of an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Load the SVG

Instead of loading the SVG directly into an image element you can use the fetch function. Here a data URL, just for the example -- it can just be replaced by a URL. At this point you could store the SVG in a variable.

###### Parsing the SVG

To change the SVG one approach could be to use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath). This is what happens in the function changeAttribute() that takes the SVG, an XPath expression and an object containing the data about what to change.

###### Load the SVG into an image element and render in canvas

As I read your question you already figured this out. In the function insertIntoCanvas() turn the SVG (XML document) into a data URL by using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). After that the image is created and drawn on the canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

fetch('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAgMTAiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTSA1IDAgTCAwIDUgTCA1IDEwIEwgMTAgNSBaIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    let xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
    changeAttribute(xmlDoc, '//svg:path', {fill:'red'});
    changeAttribute(xmlDoc, '//svg:svg', {width:100, height:100});
    insertIntoCanvas(xmlDoc);
  });

function insertIntoCanvas(xmlDoc){
  let file = new File([xmlDoc.rootElement.outerHTML], 'svg.svg', {
    type: "image/svg+xml"
  });
  // and a reader
  let reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.addEventListener('load', e => {
    /* create a new image assign the result of the filereader
    to the image src */
    let img = new Image();
    // wait for it to got load
    img.addEventListener('load', e => {
      // update canvas with new image
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
    });
    img.src = e.target.result;
  });
  // read the file as a data URL
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function changeAttribute(doc, xpath, obj) {
  let r = doc.evaluate(xpath, doc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

  let nodes = [];
  let next = r.iterateNext();
  while (next) {
    nodes.push(next);
    next = r.iterateNext();
  }

  nodes.forEach(node => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      node.setAttribute(key, obj[key]);
    });
  });
}

function nsResolver(prefix) {
  const ns = {
    'xhtml': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  };
  return ns[prefix] || null;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to:

- load the **external** SVG file as *text*
- inject it in a shadowDOM (the browser will do the parsing)
- **add** your `<style>` elements
- extract the SVG `outerHTML`
- replace invalid URI characters **"** and **#**
- create a `<canvas>`
- write SVG to `canvas.img` as XML **DataURI**
- add your `<canvas>` to the shadowDOM
  or `replaceWith` the Web Component that did the work

A **native JavaScript** Web Component `<svg-to-canvas>`, supported in all modern browsers,
can it do all for you, so you only write:

```html
<svg-to-canvas src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
  <style>
    svg  { background:green }
    path { fill:red }
  </style>
</svg-to-canvas>
```

[image]

#### JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/cosfrqyv/

#### StackOverflow snippet:

```html
<style>
  svg-to-canvas { background: lightgreen }
  canvas { background:pink }
</style>
  <svg-to-canvas src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg">
    <style>
      svg  { background:green }
      path { fill:red }
    </style>
  </svg-to-canvas>
  <svg-to-canvas replaceWith src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-to-canvas>
<script>
customElements.define("svg-to-canvas", class extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback(svg,canvas,img) {
    this.style.display   = "inline-block";
    this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .innerHTML = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text();
    svg = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg");
    svg.append(...this.querySelectorAll("*"));
    // stop here for an SVG inside shadowDOM
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    img    = Object.assign(new Image(), {
               onload : () => {
                 canvas.width = img.width; canvas.height = img.height;
                 canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
               },
               src : "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,"
                     + svg.outerHTML.replace(/"/g, "'").replace(/#/g, "%23")
            });
    if (this.hasAttribute("replaceWith")) this.replaceWith(canvas);
    else { svg.remove();  this.shadowRoot.append(canvas) }
  }
})
</script>
```